# Ibm_db gem- could not load

Tags: ruby

I try to run the query from Ruby using `IBM_DB` driver

IBM DB HOME path is set

`ibm_db` gem is installed (ibm_db-3.0.4)

The run error out saying

> cannot load such file -- mswin32/ibm_db (LoadError)

though i tried the below 2 statements.

```
require 'mswin32/ibm_db'
```

or

```
require "ibm_db"
```

Ruby is `64-bit` and version `2.2.4`. Please help on what could be missed

Comment: Is there any gem's dependency that maybe you're missing?

Comment: gem succesfully installed. appears in the gem list. surprisingly when run, throws the error

Comment: And that's why I'm asking if gems demands any dependency. Also, what's the compatibility of the gem with your system ?